# iOS Display rich text contains animated GIF

Tags: ios, uilabel, animated-gif, richtext

I want to display a html contains an image link.
And the image is an animated GIF.
I want to display the rich content and let the GIF be animated.
Is there any solution to accomplish it?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried with an UIWebView? Downloading the gift and locally building a web page, and showing it in a UIWebView?

Comment: @Raspu: I'm going to use it in an UITableView, so this is not an option due to performance issue.

Comment: I see, for the gif part, you can use this library: https://github.com/ondalabs/OLImageView. For the Rich text, you probably should use a NSAttributedString. But I don't think there is anything that solves both problems..

Comment: Anyway, you need to show this inside a cell?

Comment: @Raspu: Yes. I guess I need a UILabel both support rich text and animated GIF.

Comment: So you need to show a gif inline inside the UILabel... That's difficult, I think you will need to go with coreGraphics, sorry.